# como aplicar a verificação por json no js?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estou criando um formulário e quero validar o CPF da pessoa da seguinte forma, se o CPF da pessoa já estiver no arquivo json o programa deve dar um alert falando que o usuário já tem cadastro, porém não sei como fazer essa autenticação?!

```html
 <body id="fundo">
    <form action="autenticacao.json" method="post" name="dados" onsubmit="return validaForm(this);" id="paraForm">

      <div>
        <label for="tx_cpf">CPF:</label>
        <input name="tx_cpf" type="text" id="tx_cpf" OnClick="validaForm" />
        
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Esse é os dados do arquivo json:

```
{ "dadosUsi" : {
"tx_cpf" : 123456789123 
}}
```

Meu js:

```js
function validaForm(frm) {

  if (tx_cpf.value == "" ) {
    alert("Por favor, CPF invalido.");

    return false;
  }
 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Coloque sua função valida form também

Comment: pronto, coloquei a função

Comment: Isso deveria ser feito no servidor, não no browser via js.

Comment: Php seria melhor então?

Comment: Se php seria melhor ou não isso já está fora do escopo, entrando em linguagens de preferencias... Sendo assim você pode usar qualquer uma que faça o server side, seja NodeJS, PHP etc...

Comment: Você pode fazer a verificação com Ajax, não precisa de um formulário para isto, faz uma requisição para o arquivo json e veja se o que for digitado no input já existe no arquivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há uma série de inconsistências no seu código e eu vou ir citando elas no decorrer da resposta, vamos começar pelo *html*, você está fazendo uma ação para um arquivo *json* é isso mesmo? Não tem sentido você fazer isso tendo em vista que o *JSON* não recebe requisições *GET, POST, PUT* ou *DELETE* etc... O *JSON* é como se fosse um simples arquivo de texto para organização de estruturas, não emite ou recebe requisições. Tendo em vista isso você chama *validaForm* 2 vezes, uma dentro do input quando o usuário clica e outra na submição do form, a da submissão é até aceitável, mas a do *click* no input não, pois sempre que o usuário clicar pela primeira vez esse campo será vazio. Adicione um botão ao invés disso alterando esse HTML

```js
let cpfs = '{"dadosUsi":[{"cpf":"400985123"},{"cpf":"400985124"},{"cpf":"400985125"},{"cpf":"400985126"}]}'

function validaForm() {
  let cpf = document.getElementById("tx_cpf").value;;
  
  if (cpf.trim().length === 0 ) {
    alert("Por favor, CPF invalido.");
  }
  
  alert(JSON.parse(cpfs).dadosUsi.filter(i => i.cpf === cpf).length > 0 ? "Já tem cadastro" : "Não tem cadastro") 
  
 
  return false
}
```

```html
   

<body id="fundo">
    <form action="" method="post" name="dados" onSubmit="return validaForm()" id="paraForm"> 
        <div>
        <label for="tx_cpf">CPF:</label>
        <input name="tx_cpf" type="text" id="tx_cpf" />
        <button>Checa Cpf</button>
          
       </div>
    </form>
 </body>
```

Note também que não tem sentido você ler um arquivo através do cliente pois nem sempre ele pode estar lá, sem contar que pensando em um sistema que seria utilizado por outros computadores, seria totalmente sem sentido você salvar os dados desses users no computador de cada cliente, isso deveria ser feito do lado do servidor porém fiz uma demonstração de como seria possível checar um JSON se há ou não o cpf, isso poderia ser feito usando a função [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) do javascript, como a sua finalidade não foi definida, fiz algumas alterações sempre retornando false na função para cancelar a submissão, porém não é a melhor forma, você também estava checando se o cpf era vazio sem nem ter pego o valor do mesmo.